# Can query and suggest be combined in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, elasticsearch-query

I am using ealsticsearch 5.5. I have a bool query which checks for the group the user belongs to and then "suggest" query for autocomplete. I am not able to get the desired results while combining query and suggest.
This is my "query" and "suggest" query.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "terms": {
                                    "group": [
                                        "5de6fad3f7ee821a45e8379e"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "suggest": {
        "canonical-suggest": {
            "prefix": "lee",
            "completion": {
                "field": "suggest"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is giving me all the records in the group and suggest condition is not applied.There are no errors. Is there a way i can make the query and suggest as a "and" condition. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your sample doc and expected docs so that we can test it from our side

Comment: Hi Opster ES Ninja, thank you very much for helping. I have added my requirement with the queries in the doc link below. https://docs.google.com/document/d/12nmvUibWgvyQTfKKof_2dNFQahTTqqeLVBL1GtzllFU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response, let me know if you still need answer for it?